# touch devices prevent parent element from scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, touch

I have search hundreds of times for this one, but I haven't been able to find a definite WORKING answer so I left it behind for a while, but now I came back to this problem and still can't find a solution.

I am using the following script to prevent scrolling on parent elements in browsers using a mouse, however I can't find a similar way to prevent parent elements from scrolling in TOUCH devices.

```
$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', '.parentunscroll', function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this),
        scrollTop = this.scrollTop,
        scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight,
        height = $this.height(),
        delta = (ev.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
            ev.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
            ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta),
        up = delta > 0;

    var prevent = function() {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }

    if (!up && -delta > scrollHeight - height - scrollTop) {
        // Scrolling down, but this will take us past the bottom.
        $this.scrollTop(scrollHeight);
        return prevent();
    } else if (up && delta > scrollTop) {
        // Scrolling up, but this will take us past the top.
        $this.scrollTop(0);
        return prevent();
    }
});
```

I have looked into tens of similar threads in here, but couldn't find a solution that actually works BOTH ways: Prevent parent scrolling in overflown elements on BOTH mouse AND touch events.

Hopefully, someone has already got this right; I am sure this will help lots of people with the same question.

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to prevent scroll with touch ? I wonder if your issue isn't caused by the fact that touch devices also emit fake mouse events to ensure compatibility, so you would need to handle and cancel both events.

Comment: Well, I don't have any code to show. All I have tried was not working, so I haven't saved anything. Looking for someone to provide me with a working code :/

Comment: I just checked with my input library : handling touch start/move/end/cancel with handlers that stopPropagation and preventDefault does work to prevent scroll on iPad4. 
If i understood well, you don't want to prevent scroll always but just when... it's already impossible since we reached start or end ? or did i miss something ?

Comment: The above code does not work for me on either iphone or ipad on ios 7

Comment: Could you answer my second question please ? the code shown is testing to prevent default only if the scrolling is too high or too low. Do you want to always prevent scroll on parent, or only if some conditions are met ? Maybe you want that to be able to scroll, but that the scroll does not propagate upper in the document when limit reached ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize the question at first. In the project I need this code in, it would be great if I had two different options. a) if I touch inside an element with a specific class NOT to scroll any parent at all (stay put as it is) and b) only prevent parent scroll if content is larger overflown element height (what I have now). The behavior using a mouse at this point works ALMOST as expected; it prevents parent scrolling in general, but it also prevents it even if the content is smaller than the overflown element height. I hope I am getting this across. :/ Also, thanks for your effort

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question so that we understand that you don't want to prevent scroll, but rather ''scroll overflow'', when the scroll inside an element propagates to the parent element.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. We have an element, either overflown or not, what I am looking for is when you touch drag inside this element, every other element stays as it is without scrolling when this element reaches its end.

Comment: i was justing suggesting that you write something like that in the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, but since no-one posts, i will just tell the way i think this could be done :
1) on touch event, you have a scroll event, but it is raised after the scroll begins, so even if you correct the document scroll position afterwise, there will be some very annoying moves on the screen.
2) i think the way to go is to do the same as for mouse... except that you don't have the touchscroll event... so you have to detect it 'by hand' and cancel it if you see that top/bottom are allready reached.
A difficult solution.

You might want to check for libs that does that, but the ones i know of will warn you of a scroll, but won't let you cancel it (it's too late just like in case (1)).

Hopefully someone will suggest easier way / the right library...

Comment: Thanks for your effort. As you said someone hopefully will answer. I am amazed that noone needed something similar and/or have a solution for this.